# A simple buffer for a piezoelectric pickup to mixer connection

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer

so my question is pretty straightforward: what are the ways in which this circuit is likely to fail, and how can I protect against that?

I play music (mandolin and viola) and my instruments have piezoelectric pickups, which sound kind of crap connected directly to a mixer.

I've built this buffer circuit (see image) and it works - my instruments sound significantly better. I intend to build it into a module for my instruments for use while performing live.

It is my impression that, because this circuit is so basic there shouldn't be much that can go wrong. Feel free to disabuse me of this notion - but please explain why as I wish to get a clear understanding of what I'm missing.

[image: The circuit I've come up with, which works]

**EDIT 1:** I also attempted to measure the current draw, but it's so low (well under 10mA) that my cheap multimeter couldn't measure it, and the 5V USB power bank I was using to power the circuit kept powering down. For this reason, I presume that the voltage levels will generally remain stable during use ... is that a safe assumption?

**EDIT 2:** Updated circuit design based on suggestions from @richardthespacecat and @analogsystemsrf

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFeatj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Deriving a ground reference via a resistive divider isn't usually a very good idea. I would recommend using two 9V batteries for a +9V/0V/-9V supply.

Comment: Or buffering the reference with say another opamp.

Comment: @Felthry could you explain why that's not a good idea? It was my understanding that this is only an issue when large currents are involved (see my edit). I want to keep the parts count to the bare minimum, so an additional 9V battery is really not ideal considering a single battery is bigger than the whole circuit board.

Comment: Try @RichardtheSpacecat's suggestion, then; buffer the reference with another op amp. (many op amps come in dual packages, two amplifiers in a single package, so you wouldn't be adding to the size.) Explaining why exactly it's not a good idea to make a ground reference with a voltage divider would take more awakeness than I have at the moment, though.

Comment: Or place a large capacitor on the 4.5 volt node, so RFI will not cause high-frequency common-mode problems.

Comment: @Richard The Spacecat - what you're saying is basically to duplicate the circuit, but connect the 4.5V reference where the piezo is, and then connect the output of that second circuit to the '4.5V ground' of the first circuit? Is that correct?

Comment: Basically yes! Just follow the midrail divider, and use the follower's output as your reference. @Felthry has already suggested using a dual opamp, which I second. It may also help adding some capacitor(s) from the divider's output to ground (and perhaps to the 9V as well).

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat added an updated circuit, how's that look?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf added an updated circuit based on richard's and your suggestion, how's that look?

Comment: C1 is unnecessary, but won't cause any problems. Other than that, it looks like that'll work fine.

Comment: @Felthry I take that as a vote of confidence that the second circuit diagram could be used as a reliable piece of equipment in a professional music setting?

Comment: 5532 op amps were never the best in the world. Yes they were used in pro audio because they were the only  suitable thing to use in the late 70's-80's. If I was building a single chip DI i would use an AD 8643 instead, and build it with balanced out. With a quad op amp ic you can do the preamp, line gain buffer and balanced output stages.

Comment: @drtechno I'll keep that in mind for when I start building music rigs hahah. All I'm aiming for here is just the buffer, and let the mixer take care of the rest - like I said in my post, the circuit I originally built works pretty much perfectly as-is, but if the redesigned circuit is more reliable, then that's a nice bonus.

Comment: Its the long cable run on the output to the FOH mixer makes unbalanced operation not feasible in most settings. Now if you are going into some sort of mixer on stage like the keyboard people do, then It will be compatible no matter where you gig. If you are used to coffee shop world then yes your design would work well in that setting. (just because there is no long cable runs)

Comment: @drtechno ahh I see where you're coming from. Yes, of course, you're right. I have my own mixer with me most of the time (3 images): https://www.instagram.com/p/BefsvtbD02s/

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff8FBB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. OP's Figure 2 has a few odities.*

I have a few concerns about this circuit.

- Using the op-amp output as ground is unusual. Normally the 0 V line would be considered ground. This simplifies power supply, debug and, in guitar effects units, for example, allows the battery to be connected into circuit by insertion of the jack plug.
- The piezo pickup will have an extremely high input impedance. That means there is nowhere for IC1a's bias current to go. That means that the bias current will drive the + input to one supply rail or the other.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYJJcP.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A more traditional approach.*

The normal way to do this is to use the mid-supply as a bias for the operating point of the amplifiers. Since you have chosen a non-inverting arrangement then you need to apply the bias as shown via R3.

C2 and C3 decouple the input and output and prevent the DC being affected by external connections.

Comment: A few technical questions. 1) why is it frowned upon to use the voltage divider as a reference ground (buffered or not)? I always thought voltages were relative ... and my original circuit works, as built in the first image. 2) Could you tell me what is a good value/type of cap to use for C2 and C3 that will have minimal effect on sound quality? 3) it was my understanding that coupling capacitors are only necessary for amplifiers, or for multiple stages of circuitry. Is there significant danger in omitting the caps for this single stage low power build?

Comment: 4) In my Figure 2 design, I thought that op amps can both source and sink current? So I'd have assumed that bias current could equalize between the outputs of IC1a and IC1b? To be clear, I'm not questioning your design at all, just making sure I understand what I'm doing wrong.